# Installing regular kitchen tap in caravan with garden hose

Tags: plumbing, water, faucet

I live in a caravan attached to a granny flat next to my parents' home (in Australia). I want to run water from the tanks to the van, but the van no longer has any of the original plumbing, only a regular steel sink. I have a drinking-water-safe garden-style hose that has standard click-clack fittings by default.

I was able to find a [cheap Chinese tap](https://www.caravansplus.com.au/watermark-fold-down-single-tap-right-hand-p-21023.html) designed for caravans that isn't stupidly small/short and it was listed as having 3/8" BSP threads. Then I found a [brass 3/8" BSP to 12.5mm barb adapter](https://www.caravansplus.com.au/water-brass-adapter-female-38inch-bsp-to-125mm-barb-p-6976.html), and I thought I would just hose-clamp the hose onto the brass adapter. This didn't work well for two reasons: 1) the threads on the tap are so soft that there already partly destroyed just from putting the tap into the sink hole and so require lots of thread tape to seal even a bit, and 2) I can't screw the brass adapter onto the tap after it's got the hose clamped on and it's not easy to access. I didn't think that through very well, lol.

I assumed it would be easy: go to Bunnings, pick out a tap, grab an adapter or two and screw it all together. Turns out, taps are insanely expensive, aren't easy to buy when you only have a cold input and don't seem to list thread sizes or give any guidance on what types of fittings they use.

So, how can I install a normal, everyday kitchen tap in my van and attach it to a garden hose? I'm fine with it being a mixer tap, but I'll need a Y-splitter to connect the cold water to both hot and cold inlets, and that's something else I have yet to figure out.

It's worth noting I would prefer not to use the click-clack garden hose fitting on the caravan end because I don't trust it to stay attached and not flood my van, hence the attempt at using a barb + hose clamp solution.

Comment: In the US, at least, almost any hardware store will carry brass adapters from "pipe thread" to "hose thread". Both are standardized; unfortunately they really are different standards. That plus the appropriate fitting for your "click-clack" connector, should do the job. As far as cheaper taps go: try an "architectural recycling" store like Habitat For Humanity 's "Re/Store"; they may have taps much less expensively if you're willing to take whatever style was donated as surplus or like-new used. If that fails, look for someone upgrading their taps; Freecycle is one possible community to ask.

Comment: There are adapters, but I would not trust "garden hose" plumbing inside of a building for anything more than a short period(hour) of time.  Usually not built to withstand pressure for long.

Comment: @crip659 The garden hose isn't inside the van except at the end, and the pressure isn't high. It's connected to a tank, not town mains. I'm not concerned about that. Besides, what do you expect to happen? The hose isn't going to just burst randomly 